# Are IIR filters (and specifically Butterworth filter) causal?

Tags: filters, python, infinite-impulse-response, butterworth, scipy

I am new to signal processing. I am learning now about filtering and I am trying to implement high pass filter (HPF),and later band-pass filter (BPF). I implement the filters in `Python 3.8` with `NumPy` and `SciPy`.

For the offline case (filtering a pre-recorded time) I designed a *Butterworth* high-pass filter, and applied on the signal at the time domain using `signal.filtfilt` function. However, as the documentation shows, this approach is good only for offline cases and not for real-time, since the filter scans the signal forward and then backwards. I can recover the frequency response from the filter using `signal.freqz` function.

Now I want that this filter will work also in real-time (so it needs to be causal, and I ask if this possible for this type of filters. Here are my questions:

1. If I understand correctly, Butterworth filters are IIR (infinite impulse response) filters. Is it true?
2. Are IIR filter causal? It may be that all IIR filters are not causal and it may be that some are and some are not. What are the cases in which IIR filters are causal?
3. Are Butterworth filters causal? If not always, in which case they are causal?
4. If the answer to 3 is true, how to implement a causal Butterworth filter, both at the time domain and the frequency domain? (I can use `SciPy` functions such as `signal.butter`, `signal.freqz` etc.)

Relevant links:

- [Help designing Butterworth filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8696/help-designing-butterworth-filter)
- filtfilt: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Yes, Butterworth are IIR.  The decay from an impulse technically lasts forever.
2. Yes, all [implementable] IIR are causal.
3. Yes, because of #1 and #2.
4. Don't use [`signal.filtfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html).  Use [`signal.lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html).  `filtfilt` does the same thing as `lfilter`, except twice, in opposite directions, which changes a causal filter into a zero-phase filter.

However, as the documentation for both of those functions suggests, for most practical use, you should actually use the SOS variants instead:

> The function `sosfilt` (and filter design using `output='sos'`) should be
> preferred over `lfilter` for most filtering tasks, as second-order sections
> have fewer numerical problems.

To summarize the functions:

- [`lfilter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html): Causal single-stage filtering (low orders only)
- [`filtfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html): Zero-phase single-stage filtering (low orders only)
- [`sosfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sosfilt.html): Causal second-order sections filtering
- [`sosfiltfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sosfiltfilt.html): Zero-phase second-order sections filtering

Really the only reason to use `lfilter` or `filtfilt` is if your coefficients are already in `b, a` format, if you're implementing something out of a textbook, etc.

If you're designing the filter yourself, then just use SOS form, which reduces numerical error.

Note that the `filtfilt` functions apply the filter twice, so it will have double the order of the original filter.

Comment: 2.: all implementable IIR are causal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller What's a non-implementable filter?

Comment: anything that's not causal needs values from the future, and hence can't be implemented; however, I can write down impulse responses that aren't causal without problem.

Comment: Marcus, actually one can implement non-causal IIR filter, but work with it in offline and not in real-time (e.g. filtering a WAV file). This is the case of zero-phase filter.

Comment: @endolith And how to implement it in the frequency domain?

Comment: @Triceratops What do you mean?

Comment: @Triceratops: You can TRY to make a non-causal filter causal by applying sufficient amount of bulk delay. That's what non-real processing does. Today you are processing samples which were generated yesterday. You are using some of this delay in your processing. However, for IIR that can only be done approximately since the non-causality is infinite, you technically need infinite amount of bulk delay so you need to truncate at some point. In practice, the truncation error becomes very small quickly, so it's not much of a problem, but it's never error free.

Comment: @endolith I can design a Butterworth filter, obtain its frequency response, taking abs value and obtain a zero-phase filter, which by theory is non-causal. Then I use it as a regular frequency filter.

Answer (score 2):

> Are IIR filter causal? It may be that all IIR filters are not causal and it may be that some are and some are not. What are the cases in which IIR filters are causal?

All real IIR filters are causal.  All real systems are causal, unless the universe is a lot weirder than it seems.

You can *define* a filter that acts on future information; i.e. you could say that $y_n = 0.9 y_{n+1} + x_n$.  That would (with a lot of words to overcome the reader's skepticism) describe a filter whose impulse response is
$$h_\kappa = \begin{cases}
0 & \kappa > 0 \\
0.9^{-\kappa} & \kappa \le 0
\end{cases}$$

You could not, however, actually implement such a filter in real life.

Comment: As Triceratops pointed out, one *can* run a non-causal filter on a recorded signal, because one can then peek ahead in the recording.

Comment: Yes.  But strictly speaking it's still causal, because the signal was recorded to the end before you started running your filter on it.  So you can *simulate* a non-causal filter.  But you cannot implement one in really truly real life.  Because -- Physics is Everything.

Comment: I don't think those words mean what you think. A filter you run on a recorded signal is a perfectly valid filter.

Comment: @TimWescott A non-causal filter can work on a prerecorded data (e.g. WAV file) but would not, at least according to theory, work in real-time.

Comment: Yes, a filter run on pre-recorded data is perfectly valid.  And filter that's "non-causal" in the theoretical DSP sense can be run on pre-recorded data.  But it's still causal in the physics sense -- for instance you can't run a non-causal filter on the ticker feed from your local stock exchange and make trades based on actual future stock prices.  Nor can you put a non-causal filter in the feedback path of a physical control loop.

Comment: I will try clarify with an example: suppose I have a data $x(t)$ and a filter which estimate $x(t_0)$ by $\tfrac{1}{2}( x(t_0 - 1) + x(t_0 + 1) )$. This filter is not causal and can't run real-time because it needs information from the future ($x(t_0 + 1)$), but it can work on a video recording containing $x(t)$ for $a \le t \le b$, since it has the "future" data. Of course, it doesn't violate the law of physics and physical causality because the video was recorded in the past, but it is not what I shall call a causal filter.